# Java appendChild (CSV to XML conversion) doesn't work for ONE node

Tags: java, xml, csv, appendchild, root-node

So I need to convert a CSV file to seperate XML files (one XML file per line in the CSV file). And this all works fine, except for the fact that it refuses to add one value. It adds the other without a problem, but for some mysterious reason refuses to create a tag for one of my nodes.

```
 Document newDoc = documentBuilder.newDocument();

 Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("XMLoutput");
 newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
 String header = headers.get(col);
 String value = null;
 String value2 = null;
 if (col < rowValues.length) {

 if(header.equals("delay")) {
    value = rowValues[col];
    Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong(value));
 }

 Element shipidElement = newDoc.createElement("shipID");
 shipidElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(csvFileName)));
 rootElement.appendChild(shipidElement);

 if(header.equals("centraleID")) {
      value = rowValues[col];
      System.out.println(value); //to check if the if condition works, it does
      Element centralElement = newDoc.createElement(header);
      Text child = newDoc.createTextNode(value);
      centralElement.appendChild(child);
     rootElement.appendChild(centralElement);
      }

     else if(header.equals("afstandTotKade")) {
     value2 = rowValues[col];
     Element curElement = newDoc.createElement(header);
     curElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(value2));
     rootElement.appendChild(curElement);
     }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    Element timeElement = newDoc.createElement("Timestamp");
    timeElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(timeStamp));
    rootElement.appendChild(timeElement);
   }
```

So in the above code, the if loop checking for CentraleID actually works, because it prints out the values, however the XML file does not add a tag, not even if I just insert a string instead of the header value. It does, however, insert the "afstandTotKade" node and timestamp node. I am dumbfounded.

PS: this is only part of the code of course, but the problem is so minute, that it seemed superfluous to add all of it.

PPS: the code was originally the same as the others, I've just been playing around.

This is the resulting XML File btw, so the other if does add the nodes, and I know the spelling is correct in checking the header because it does print out the values (the sout code) when I run it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<XMLoutput>
   <shipID>1546312</shipID>
   <afstandTotKade>1000</afstandTotKade>
   <Timestamp>22:06:33</Timestamp>
</XMLoutput>
```

Comment: Can you show the headers row of your CSV file please?

Comment: delay,centraleID,afstandTotKade